# Как сделать 2-ую аутентификацию с помощью email и набора цифр (без ссылок)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, mvc

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model, string returnUrl = null) 
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                // code = "AgvdHSD734BHD...Bd/jd..." а нужно "634973"
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Ваш код подтверждения", code);

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                return RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

В общем нужно, чтобы в email отправлялся код с подтверждение что то вроде "383534" а не куча непонятных символов.

Есть ли какой-то нормальный метод который генерирует токен c цифрами (**токен должен быть на email**).

Например, есть такой метод для Создания телефона вот он генерирует код. _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken

Comment: `new Random().Next(1000000).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')`

Comment: Это называется "Двухфакторная проверка подлинности (2fa)", в документации есть куча полезного на эту тему, например [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity), и тут как бы при чем `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` мне лично не понятно...

Comment: А зачем? Сформулируйте задачу

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,

Мне нужно генерировать токен для Email, чтобы в дальнейшем передать его `_userManager.ConfirmEmail(user, token)` 

Но токен не должен быть огромным, чтобы пользователь мог сам набрать его, например в виде цифр

В данной [статье](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity), которую вы указали, токен генерируется как раз таки по методу `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`, он не совсем подходит под мои задачи.

Comment: @Anatol, Пользователь регистрируется ему приходит сообщение в почту в виде цифр, а-ля подтвердите email, ваш код "458537". Данные цифры нужно ввести в поле для подтверждения email-а

Comment: Ну странная хотелка, обычно этот токен является частью ссылки, которую достаточно открыть для подтверждения. Ничего руками вводить не нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(
    user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);

//TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider - "Email"
```

Генерируется маленький код подтверждения, например: "466546".